# Find one text value that repeats more than twice from one column from table A in relation with the value of a column from table B

Tags: sql, count

So I have 2 tables

```
Table A
hotelNo | name
H1      |Okto
H2      |Petro
H3      |Duke
H5      |Caesar
H6      |Kirby

Table B
hotelNo | type
H1      |Single
H1      |Single
H1      |Double
H1      |Self
H1      |Single
H2      |Single
H2      |Single
H2      |Double
H2      |Self
H2      |Deluxe
H3      |Single
H3      |Single
H3      |Double
H3      |Self
H3      |Deluxe
H5      |Single
H5      |Single
H5      |Double
H5      |Double
H5      |Double
H6      |Single
H6      |Double
```

Now, I need to List hotelNo who have more than 2 double rooms. Meaning H# = 'Double' > 2
The desired Result should be something like this:
hotelNo | type | count
H5      |Double|3

I have spent more 24 hours trying to solve this, but this is the farther I got:

SELECT a.hotelNo, b.type, count(b.type = 'Double') > 2
FROM TableA a, TableB b
WHERE b.type = 'Double'

--BUT it does not work. It shows instead:
hotelNo | type | count(b.type = 'Double')
H1      |Double|1

HELP PLEASE!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be on the right track.  You may restrict to only double rooms, then aggregate by hotel and assert the count:

```
SELECT
    a.hotelNo,
    a.name
FROM TableA a
INNER JOIN TableB b
    ON a.hotelNo = b.hotelNo
WHERE
    b.type = 'Double'
GROUP BY
    a.hotelNo,
    a.name
HAVING
    COUNT(*) > 2;
```

Comment: Done! Sorry, I'm new here.